# Subtotals and Grand totals

Tags: tableau-api

There are options to set both subtotals and grand totals at the top or both at the bottom, but is there a way to have subtotals at the top and the grand total at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there really isn't an easy way to do this.  I recommend you use two sheets and put them on a dashboard to get the combination of vizzes that match your requirements.